Command::Prohibit() seems to have no effect
In Laravel I learnt of a new method

Command::prohibit();

combined with

DB::prohibitDestructiveCommands();

This should prevent a command from running in your code.  The idea is to use on Commands that should not run in production.
However it does not for me.
I have added the prohibitable trait to my command and called CoursePayment::prohibit() but to no avail, my command still runs.  I have tried setting the parameter rather than relying on the default, but no luck. I have tried it in dev and production.
Am I missing something really simple to get prohibit() working on my Command?

This question is similar to: Is there a way to disable artisan commands?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks, but its not the same.  I know how to do it, I'm having difficulty getting it to work.

Show us what exactly you've done, then. We can't fix code we can't see. Ref: [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. You have enough previous reputation to know how this site works

@TobyAllen doesnt that answer your question ?

This does answer my question but it not what I was expecting.

the Command::prohibit() method is part of the trait \Illuminate\Console\Prohibitable which is used in 4 commands as of laravel 11
WipeCommand, ResetCommand, FreshCommand and RefreshCommand. It's not part of the main class Command.
Those 4 classes have at the start of their handle() method:
public function handle()
{
    if ($this->isProhibited() ||
        ! $this->confirmToProceed()) { //this is part of the trait ConfirmableTrait
        return Command::FAILURE;
    }
    //...
}

So if you wanna add it to any command, you need to use the trait and add the verification at the handle() method.
use use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
//...

public function handle()
{
    if ($this->isProhibited()) {
        return Command::FAILURE;
    }
    //...
}

